# Python Pandas Bar Chart - change color for specific bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have some data in csv.

It has only one column and contents strings with soccer scores like "0:0","1:2",etc.

Then I building histogam with `df[0].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')`.

What is the best way to change color only for bars with "draw" score (0:0, 1:1,...)?

I can add second column with '1' for draws and '0' for others, but don't understand how to use it as bar color.

I tried solution from another question here

`df[0].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', color=(df[1] == 1).map({True: 'orange', False: 'blue'}))` but got wrong coloring

[wrong coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSnB5.png), expecting orange "1:1"
example dataframe:

```
      0  1
0   2:0  0
1   2:3  0
2   1:1  1
3   1:3  0
4   2:0  0
5   3:4  0
6   1:2  0
7   0:1  0
8   2:3  0
9   0:1  0
10  1:1  1
11  2:1  0
12  0:1  0
13  1:2  0
14  0:3  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)  for test if match `1` column with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for array of colors passed to `color` parameter:

```
a = df[0].value_counts()
colors = np.where(a.index.isin(df.loc[df[1] == 1, 0].unique()), 'orange', 'blue')
a.plot(kind='bar', color=colors)
```

[image: g]

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Is there way to do it without numpy?

Comment: if use panas, also use numpy, so if use `pd.np.where` instead `np.where` it working

Comment: @dad or use `colors = a.index.isin(df.loc[df[1] == 1, 0].unique()).map({True: 'orange', False: 'blue'})`

Comment: @dad or use `colors = a.index.isin(df.loc[df[1] == 1, 0].unique()).to_series().map({True: 'orange', False: 'blue'})` if oldier pandas version